# How can I append form input fields to a master field via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, input, append

I'm attempting to auto-fill a form field based on other form field values.

For example, if I ask for three names, I want another field (#MyInput) to populate based on those three names.

```
name 1 <input type="type" value="" class="names" /><br />
name 2 <input type="type" value="" class="names" /><br />
name 3 <input type="type" value="" class="names" /><br />
list <input type="text" id="MyInput" /><br />
```

script:

```
$('.names').keyup(function() {
var myInput = $('#MyInput').val('')[0];

$('.names').val().each(function(){
 myInput.value += this.value + ' ';

});
}).keyup();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SQcGq/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.names').val().each(function(){
 myInput.value += this.value + ' ';

});
}).keyup();
```

should be

```
$('.names').each(function(){
 myInput.value += this.value + ' ';

});
}).keyup();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SQcGq/22/